# Visual Studio Community 2015 and MVC2 template

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

i'm trying to create project with tutorial of ASP.Net programming but at first step,  teacher told me to create project from online template named ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application.

screen: http://img2.altcontroldelete.pl/images/thumbs/09b32b23-5f25-9204-7140-0a112c6e81f4.jpg

Unfortunnetly I can't find it in my diag. In online projects I don't have any templates.

screen: http://prnt.sc/b1y42k

Is in VS Community 2015 this is avalaible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools>>Nuget Package Manger >> Package Manger Console

use command "Install-Package Mvc2" and press enter you are able to see MVC2 templates

Comment: PM> Install-Package Mvc2
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Mvc2.2.0.1' with respect to project 'WebSite2', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Mvc2.2.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Mvc2.2.0.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'Mvc2.2.0.1'

Comment: Adding package 'Mvc2.2.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite2\packages'
Added package 'Mvc2.2.0.1' to folder 'C:\Users\bob\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite2\packages'
Added package 'Mvc2.2.0.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Mvc2 2.0.1' to WebSite2

Comment: this is response from consle but in solution explorer i don'ts see controllers,  views and models

also I don't see new template

Comment: may be you choose empty template project

Comment: still nothing in empty template project

Answer (score 0):

I get it resolved by re-installing/Update the setup.

-Restart the setup for VS2015 Preview -Selected the required components to install
[image]

After these steps, I received the desired templates.

Whenever anyone is installing VS2015 Preview first time, please Select the features under 'Optional features to install' to get the desired installation.

Comment: [code]
    Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.

Comment: While looking into "Add / remove programs" -> "Visual 2015" -> "Modify" , I found the "Web developer tools" unchecked. This SO answer helps me to figure this.

After reinstalling this, everything reappears

Please see my update answer above.

Comment: no problem dear go through the re-installing VS-2015 and select the features under 'Optional features "Microsoft Web Developer tool" to install to get the desired installation.

Comment: i tried but without succes. reinstalled whole vs 2015 community and nothing.

http://prnt.sc/b20786